# In what job description do fraud prevention and coding mix?

Tags: software-industry, job-description

I work in the IT industry, specifically I'm a full stack web developer in such a language that I can easily transition into desktop or server applications.

Recently there was an incident that needed me to go through a lot of data looking for signs of fraud.

This led me to discover that I'm actually quite passionate about this kind of work.

My question is sorts of positions can I move to, to do full-time fraud investigations, looking trough data trying to spot the needle in the haystack while still be heavily linked to IT ?

(Hope I'm on-topic)

Comment: Digital forensics is the field that comes to mind. If you have an econ degree, you could even work for an insurance company as an analyst doing fraud detection.

Comment: You also may want to take a look into this (slightly unrelated but not far-off)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_technology_audit

Comment: Career advice is off-topic here. Try [chat] or a specialised forum.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

[Database Forensics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_forensics)

> Database forensics is a branch of digital forensic science relating to the forensic study of databases and their related metadata.
>
> The discipline is similar to computer forensics, following the normal forensic process and applying investigative techniques to database contents and metadata. Cached information may also exist in a servers RAM requiring live analysis techniques.
>
> A forensic examination of a database may relate to the timestamps that apply to the update time of a row in a relational table being inspected and tested for validity in order to verify the actions of a database user. Alternatively, a forensic examination may focus on identifying transactions within a database system or application that indicate evidence of wrongdoing, such as fraud.

Comment: Also compliance auditing for financial institutions or specialised government audits. AML/CFT etc, (anti money laundering/counter financing of terrorism)